# Migrate ehcache:proxy to spring 4

Tags: java, spring, xsd, ehcache, xsd-validation

I am upgrading an application from Jboss 4.2.2 / java 6 / Spring 2.5.4 to Wildfly 9.0.2 / java 8 / Spring 4.3.2.

Spring/Ehcache has made a lot of changes to their interfaces and workflow and I am unable to find any information on why my xml is no longer correct.

The declaration I'm having a problem with:

```
<ehcache:proxy id="itemDaoCacheProxy" refId="itemDao">
    <ehcache:caching methodName="getAllItemNo" cacheName="itemTableCache" />
</ehcache:proxy>
```

The error message:

> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 98 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-cfg.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 98; columnNumber: 54; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'cache:proxy'.

My xml declaration looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
```

I am using spring-context-support.jar for chache utility, but the problem seems to be isolated to the xml file and the schemas. The "proxy" element seems to have dissepeared in the later versions.

Old:

> https://github.com/zznate/spring-modules-ehcache/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springmodules/cache/config/ehcache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd

New:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd

What exacly does ehcache:proxy do and how can I migrate this to the new standard?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post details the method I used to migrate the system.

http://springtips.blogspot.se/2007/06/caching-methods-result-using-spring-and_23.html

```
<bean id="itemDaoCacheProxyMethodCache" class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="advice">
        <bean id="methodCacheInterceptor" class="com.myproject.mymodule.MethodCacheInterceptor">
            <property name="cache">
                <bean id="methodCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
                    <property name="cacheManager">
                        <ref bean="ehcache"/>
                    </property>
                    <property name="cacheName">
                        <value>itemTableCache</value>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="mappedName" value="getAllItemNo"/>
</bean>

<bean id="itemDaoCacheProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="itemDao"/>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>itemDaoCacheProxyMethodCache</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What the code does is it creates a new container that wraps my class and implements cache functionality for the specified function.

This means that there can be instances of the class where some are checking/updating cached responses and some are not.